# Rotation of parabola

Tags: optics, rotation

I'm designing a parabolic solar concentrator and am doing ray-tracing on Matlab from scratch.  I'm beginning to look into compound concentrators and would need to have an equation for a parabola rotated by x degrees centered at a specific (non origin) point.  The equation I am using for my parabolas is $ a*(x-X)^2 - Y $.

I am not sure how to rotate this equation besides using a rotation matrix, solving for y using quadratic equation and choosing one term.  Even this method gives me another parabola in $y(x)$.

Any suggestions on a simple way to get half of a parabola rotated by $ \theta $? Should I be looking into parameterization?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it rotated around the central axis of the parabola, or an arbitrary axis? I would think that rotation around the central axis would be relatively easy, and that rotation around an arbitrary axis would be much more difficult.

Comment: A rotated parabola is _not_ a function and therefore you only choice is to use a rotation matrix.

Comment: I think it is easier to rotate the rays, and keep the paraboloid fixed.

Comment: Why are you ray tracing in the first place?

Comment: http://www.powerfromthesun.net/Book/chapter09/chapter09_files/image011.jpg  The bold lines are what I want to define in matlab as a reflective surface.  Only problem is parabolas have tilted axes.  So I would like to rotate and then select for the lower term of the quadratic (making it a function).

Comment: ray tracing because I am changing a bunch of parameters and am trying to optimize concentration numerically.

Comment: And it has to be an arbitrary axis, which makes the algebra using a rotation matrix pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is useful, but I would proceed with the parametrization and the rotation matrix, anyway.

Let us rename $x-X\rightarrow x$. Then, notice that the equation of the parabola $y = a x^2$ can be parametrized by $x = t$, $y = a t^2$, as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$; or, as a vector,

$$ (x(t), y(t))=(t,a t^2) $$

To rotate the graph of the parabola about the origin, you must rotate each point individually. Rotation clockwise by an angle $\theta$ is a linear transformation with matrix

$$  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta  \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta  \\  \end{array} \right)  $$

Thus, if we apply this linear transformation to a point $(t, t^2)$ on the graph of the parabola, we get

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta  \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta  \\  \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
t \\
a t^2\\  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
t\cos\theta +a t^2\sin\theta\\
-t\sin\theta+a t^2\cos\theta\\  \end{array} \right)$$

So, as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, this is a parametrization of the graph of the rotated parabola.Then you have to convert back to $x$ and $y$, put them in the equation $y=x^2$ and that's it.

To get a cartesian equation for the new parabola, you can just solve for $t$ in the first line $a t^2 + t cot\theta = x/\sin\theta$ and put the expression for $t$ in the second one. Doing this, you have an equation for $x$ and $t$ that corresponds to the "constraint" $x$ and $y$ must satisfy to be on the new parabola!

Comment: so from the rotated parameterized matrix at the end, converting this back to x and y simply gives [xcos() + ysin(), -xsin() + ycos()], which is just [x,y] rotated by theta, correct?  Is there a specific way to convert this back into cartesian to be useful?

Comment: I edited, maybe this is more clear! Isn't it?

Comment: Good idea! I'd add that leaving things in parametric form may be useful, as it makes computing a surface normal trivial.